# Flash (actionscript) Strange error at runtime TypeError: Error #1009: at global/avmplus::describeType()

Tags: actionscript-3

When I call describeType(object) with not-null object I have this error:

> Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

What could it be?

I am using Flex SDK 4.6.

Comment: Can you provide your actual code that is causing this problem?

Comment: You must either be passing in `null`, or you are trying to access a child of the XML object returned by `describeType` that does not exist (e.g., if you are passing in a simple Object (`{}`), the XML object returned by `describeType`has no child nodes at all).

Comment: Guys, there is no special about my code, it is

var type:XML = describeType(object, avmplus.INCLUDE_VARIABLES);

and object is not null.
regarding the flags- they do not affect anything, I tried different flags- nothing is changing

Answer (score 0):

Please put check before accessing any object where any chances to come null value/getting null by chance. if(objName != null){ //write down your code } ...it will never give 1009 error. but first of identify the from where and why you are getting null reference of your accessed object. 
this is proper way to identify and resolve the problem. but after getting problem, if it is not resolvable then please apply work around which i suggested.